# How can I play a Youtube video in AVPlayer?

Tags: objective-c, ios, video, youtube, avplayer

How can I stream a Youtube video to AVPlayer? Is there a way I can get the status of the video (buffering, paused, playing, etc)?

Comment: Were you ever able to do this? Did you find out if it's even possible?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can play YouTube video's on AVPlayer.
Using observer you can determine the state of the AVPLayer.

For example:

```
let player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.sample.com/movie.mov"))
if (player.rate != 0 && player.error == nil) {
   println("playing")
}

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(
    AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTimeNotification, 
    object: nil, 
    queue: nil, 
    usingBlock: { notification in
        self.stop()
    })
```

Comment: what you have mentioned above is streaming of  movie using avplayer but the question asked is whether the embedded youtube url, can be streamed. where currently youtube streaming is not supported unless it is unwrapped